Trying to hide an element using TamperMonkey userscript
Objective
I am trying to hide an element using Temper Monkey user script
The testing webpage is https://www.dmla5.com/play/8733-1-5.html.
After clicking the pink button, a video will be loaded.
My goal is to hide the progress bar below the video.

Simplified version that sums up the objective
document.getElementsByClassName("leleplayer-bar")[0].hidden = true;

Code
The element is loaded after a button click, so I had to add delays.
Currently, it works when directly pasted into the Google Chrome dev console but doesn't work as a user script, please take a look at my code
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Hide leleplayer-bar
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Hides elements with class leleplayer-bar
// @author       Your name
// @match        */*/*
// @grant        none
// @run-at       document-start
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    function hideElement() {
        var elementsToHide = document.getElementsByClassName("leleplayer-bar");
        if (elementsToHide.length != 0) {
            var elementToHide = elementsToHide[0];
            console.log("Target element found. Hiding...");
            elementToHide.hidden = true;
            console.log("Element hidden successfully.");
            return 1;
            console.log("Observation stopped.");
        } else {
            console.log("Target element not found.");
        }
        return 0;
    }

    function observeDOM() {
        var targetNode = document.body;
        var config = { childList: true, subtree: true };

        var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutationsList, observer) {
            for (var mutation of mutationsList) {
                if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
                    if (hideElement() === 1) {
                        observer.disconnect();
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        observer.observe(targetNode, config);
    }

    setTimeout(function() {
        if (hideElement() === 0) {
            observeDOM();
        }
    }, 1000);
})();

Problem
As mentioned, the code works when pasted directly on the console. and when I use it as temper monkey userscript code, console shows:
Target element not found.
Target element not found.
Target element not found.
Target element not found.
...

I don't understand why it isn't detecting the element when running as a user script

There's no need to use setTimeout if you're using MutationObserver.

I think the site may be doing something to interfere. When I try to use DevTools to see what's going on, it keeps doing eval("debugger") and nothing runs. I never see any log messages that I add to the script.

The element you are targeting is within an <iframe>.
We can hide the element by simply giving it a style using GM_addStyle, no setTimeout or MutationObserver needed.
You might want to hide the other associated elements (time, preview), using leleplayer-bar-wrap instead of leleplayer-bar.
Make sure your script is matching the correct iframe, in this case: https://danmu.yhdmjx.com/
Also, I don't see a  reason to run the script at document-start.
Overall, the final script should look like this:
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Hide leleplayer-bar
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Hides elements with class leleplayer-bar
// @author       Your name
// @match        https://danmu.yhdmjx.com/*
// @grant        GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

GM_addStyle('.leleplayer-bar-wrap { display: none; }');


It worked perfectly! This made my day. Thank you so much for sharing your expertise. I truly appreciate your help
